# Rendering multiple loading messages while waiting for API requests in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, async-await

I'm trying to create a react app which would get and display new quotes, each time you press the "Get quote" button. I'm getting those quotes by using an API.

The main issue I'm facing is the fact that I want a "Loading..." message over each such quote box, since APIs can sometimes be slow.

So for example, if the user presses the "Get quote" button twice, first 2 new fields should appear with "Loading..." in them, then once the API responds, those "Loading..." messages would be replaced with the actual quotes.

How can I execute something like that?

This is the code that I currently have. It does add new quotes, but it never shows the "Loading..." message, even though it seems like it should.

QuotesLogic.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import QuoteList from './QuoteList';

export default function QuotesLogic() {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuote();
  }, []);

  const fetchQuote = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.quotable.io/random');
    const data = await response.json();
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))  // 1 sec wait for testing
    setQuotes([...quotes, data]);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))  // 1 sec wait for testing
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <button onClick={fetchQuote}>Generate new</button>
      <QuoteList quotes={quotes} />
    </section>
  );
}
```

QuoteList.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import QuoteItem from './QuoteItem';

export default function QuoteList({ quotes }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {quotes.map((quote, index) => (
        <QuoteItem key={index} quote={quote} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

QuoteItem.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function QuoteItem({ quote }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='border border-green-500'>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>{quote.content}</p>
          <p className='text-right'>{quote.author}</p>
          <p>insert other quote attributes</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Oh also, the actual project I'm working on is more complicated, I just thought that a simplified version like this one would be easier to comprehend. I tried to strip it off any unimportant details.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is because loading is set to false because of useEffect in QuoteItem.jsx, you can try something like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function QuoteItem({ quote }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(setLoading(false), 5000)

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='border border-green-500'>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>{quote.content}</p>
          <p className='text-right'>{quote.author}</p>
          <p>insert other quote attributes</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but sadly that doesn't seem to be working.